# loading and manipulating data from a textfile in python

Tags: python, function

TLDR: I want to print c at the bottom but to do that I have to make arrest and brest float. I cant do that

I've made a function that reads a file and separates the first line from the rest I have two files I'm using for this aaa.txt and bbb.txt
then i try to manipulate the data. I try squaring each element of each string i realise I need to float it. I followed some guys advice but I still can't multiply stuff

is there any way I can make the brest or arrest into an array and rename them a_array. so i can just type a_array**2=h print(h)     ?

but I'm really struggling to make it work. please copy and paste stuff and see if it works because I've been taking peoples suggestions for hours and nothing works. its 5 am I'm dying over here :(

aaa.txt is below

```
test a line 1

3,6,8,99,-4,0.6,8

0,9,7,5,7,9,5

2,2,2,2,2,2,5

7,5,1,2,12,8,0.9
```

bbb.txt is below

```
test b line 1

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

55,0,90,09,1,2,3,

8,9,7,6,8,7,6

3,43,5,8,2,4,1

def mi_func(P):
    f=open(P, 'r')
    first = f.readline()
    restlines= f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return first, restlines

afirst,arest = mi_func('aaa.txt')
bfirst,brest = mi_func('bbb.txt')

#this ensures there are no standalone new line characters like ['\n', '5,6'..]
arest = [x for x in arest if x != '\n'] 
brest = [x for x in arest if x != '\n']

for i in range(len(arest)):
    arest[i] = [float(x)**2 for x in arest[i].strip().split(',') if x != '\n']


for i in range(len(brest)):
    brest[i] = [float(x) for x in brest[i].strip().split(',') if x != '\n']

print(arest)

c=(arest**2)+(brest**2)
print(c)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-629073a6846e> in <module>()
     22 print(arest)
     23 
---> 24 c=(arest**2)+(brest**2)
     25 print(c)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was you were trying to square and add the list whereas you should perform math operations on individual float elements of the list. Here is your solution:

Modify the last part of your code to this:

```
c = arest[:] # this just clones arest into c
for i in range(len(arest)):
    for j in range(len(arest[i])):
        c[i][j] = (arest[i][j]**2)+(brest[i][j]**2)
print(c)
```

And `c` should now have the sum of both the arrays squares!

***Edit 1:*** If you now want to square C or do other math operations on it,

(i) either do

```
for i in range(len(c)):
    for j in range(len(c[i])):
        c[i][j] = c[i][j]**2
```

(ii) or you could do it at first time initialization itself in

```
c[i][j] = ((arest[i][j]**2)+(brest[i][j]**2))**2
```

Comment: hey that just add them all together into one number.

i want an array of the first elements squared then added together, then the second and third and so on

Comment: @daveryanson okay, I have modified the code so C is a list that has the sum of the squares individually. Does this answer your question?

Comment: i hate to be annoying but apparently the double [][] and i don't know the correct syntax to replace it 

c=[][]
for i in range(len(arest)):
    for j in range(len(arest[i])):
        c[i][j] = (arest[i][j]**2)+(brest[i][j]**2)
print(c)

  File "<ipython-input-13-75bdb7753c93>", line 25
    c=[][]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @daveryanson I know, I fixed it now, try this, it works like you expected

Comment: i need arest. is there no way to have arest**2 +brest**2 = crest?

Comment: @daveryanson C now has the list of float numbers having the sum of squares. Please check it and let me know if it works for you!

Comment: @daveryanson yes, now `arest` remains intact. I have cloned `c` and modified it.

Comment: 1 little thing, what does [:] mean
in c = arest[:]
for i in range(len(arest)):

Comment: because I'm trying to now square root each element of c

        c[i][j] = (arest[i][j]**2)+(brest[i][j]**2)
print(c)

import math

# calculate square-root
d= c[:]
for i in range(len(c)):
    d[i]=math.sqrt(c[i])
print(d)

and the result is 

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-684dcd712c8b> in <module>()
     36 d= c[:]
     37 for i in range(len(c)):
---> 38     d[i]=math.sqrt(c[i])
     39 print(d)

TypeError: must be real number, not list

Comment: @daveryanson I have added code for squaring C in my original answer, check it

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing there is reading the same file twice,so restlines read the whole file and passes the fist line which is a string and it fails.
there are better way to do what you are doing but following your context,this should fix the problem
 change this line

```
restlines= f.readlines()[1:]
```